# Unauthorized URL redirect via HTTP host poisoning vulnerability with Jenkins

Tags: security, jenkins, header, http-headers, inject

We have noticed if we change the host header in HTTP request for Jenkins and fire the request then Jenkins is vulnerable through http host header injection.

Change the Jenkins request host header to say xyz.com, then it successfully redirects to xyz.com.

How do we address this vulnerability of Jenkins?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Front-End with Apache httpd webserver is the best i can suggest @CharlesMorin

Comment: My Jenkins instance is already fronted by Apache. Did you go for specific rewrite rules? Thanks for sharing the recipe :)

Comment: Yes @CharlesMorin

Comment: Mind sharing what was required to fix this please? Thank you.